# Export chrooted logs from a pbuilder-dist build

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, logs, pbuilder-dist

I'm using `pbuilder-dist` to test a build against a specific Ubuntu release and architecture. When I build [SiLK 3.10.2](https://tools.netsa.cert.org/silk/download.html#release-3.10.2) for i386 on 14.04 (trusty), one of the make tests fail:

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2/src/rwconvert'
PASS: tests/rwallformats-help.pl
PASS: tests/rwallformats-version.pl
PASS: tests/rwallformats-lone-command.pl
PASS: tests/rwrtd2split-help.pl
PASS: tests/rwrtd2split-version.pl
PASS: tests/rwrtd2split-lone-command.pl
FAIL: tests/rwallformats-all.pl
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for SiLK 3.10.2
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 7
# PASS:  6
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See src/rwconvert/test-suite.log
Please report to netsa-help@cert.org
============================================================================
make[5]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2/src/rwconvert'
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2/src/rwconvert'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2/src/rwconvert'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2/src'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/silk-3.10.2'
dh_auto_test: make -j1 check returned exit code 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
E: Failed autobuilding of package
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting run/shm filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
I: cleaning the build env 
I: removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//37742 and its subdirectories
```

I would like to get the log file `src/rwconvert/test-suite.log` the output above refers to, but how can I extract this file from the chrooted build environment, or get `pbuilder-dist` to output this file as well?

PS: my `$HOME/pbuilder/trusty-i386_result/` directory only contains the console output and a log file called `last_operation.log`. But `last_operation.log` lists only the output from the cleaning of the build environment (which is executed after the build failed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to solve this, so I'll answer my own question.

The solution was to use a **[hook script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto#Running_a_Shell_When_Build_Fails_.28Intro_to_Hook_Scripts.29)** to pbuilder. The linked article describe it well, but for the sake of completeness, I'll redo the steps here:

First create a directory for you hook scripts:

```
sudo mkdir /var/cache/pbuilder/hook.d
```

Then add this directory to pbuilder's configuration:

```
echo HOOKDIR=\"/var/cache/pbuilder/hook.d\" >> ~/.pbuilderrc
```

Create a hook script called C10shell with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# invoke shell if build fails.

apt-get install -y --force-yes vim less bash
cd /tmp/buildd/*/debian/..
/bin/bash < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2> /dev/tty
```

Save it to your `HOOKDIR`, and make it executeable

```
sudo chmod a+x /var/cache/pbuilder/hook.d/C10shell
```

Now, if the build fails, you will be presented with a root shell within the chrooted environment of pbuilder.